# How to lexically turn off Perl's AUTOLOAD subroutine?

Tags: perl, hook, subroutine

I'm traped in legacy code which uses Perl's `AUTOLOAD` subroutine. Every unmapped/not defined subroutine will be handled by `AUTOLOAD`. Is it possible to disable the `AUTOLOAD` handling in a lexical environment?

This solution does not work:

```
# ENTER CODE HERE
{
  # Turn off AUTOLOAD for this block.
  local *AUTOLOAD;
  undef *AUTOLOAD;

  # ENTER CODE HERE
}
# ENTER CODE HERE
```

Comment: Might be cleaner to add `die "Call to nonexistant method $AUTOLOAD" if $AUTOLOAD_DISABLED;` to your `AUTOLOAD`. (Then just do `local $AUTOLOAD_DISABLED = 1;`.)

Comment: I added a warning an require all missing scripts within the defect script. so now it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AUTOLOAD is specific to the package in question. So redefine the package method:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

{
    package autoloading;

    sub AUTOLOAD {
        print "YEAH ${AUTOLOAD}!\n";
    }

    sub new {
        return bless {}, $_[0];
    }
}

$obj = new autoloading();

$obj->foo();

*{autoloading::AUTOLOAD} = sub {};

$obj->bar();
```

Produces output:

```
YEAH autoloading::foo!
```

(no line for the `$obj->bar()` call)

Comment: I tried this without the package and it not work. So I have setup this for all packages including `main::` and now it works :)